# Detect and quantify consecutive days with values greather than a certain value

Tags: r

I have a dataset with daily variation records for temperature (Maximum - minimum) and I want to know how many consecutive days reach values higher than X.

my dataset looks like

```
         date    Max    Min  difT
1: 2012-06-15 28.369 22.944 5.425
2: 2012-06-16 27.776 20.793 6.983
3: 2012-06-17 28.692 22.154 6.538
4: 2012-06-18 28.221 23.136 5.085
5: 2012-06-19 26.793 23.689 3.104
6: 2012-06-20 29.065 24.605 4.460
```

So, for example, I want to detect and quantify how many consecutive days (date) reach difT values over 5. In the example, if my threshold is 5 degrees, the output should indicate 1 period of 4 consecutive days.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output in the example you provided?

Comment: In the example, if I'm asking for a period of consecutive days exceeding 5ºC (difT) e output should be 1 period of 4 consecutive days